# How to get Tinder user _id info from expired share URL?

Tags: api, tinder

Does anyone know, cant i retrieve user's _id from en **expired** share link (i.e "go.tinder.com/SlTqHmJVYDg-Lauren")?
so [https://api.gotinder.com/user/~SlTqHmJVYDg](https://api.gotinder.com/user/%7ESlTqHmJVYDg) returns 403 Forbidden and

```
{
    "error": "Link expired"
}
```